# .NET/C# client certificate authentication and impersonation

Tags: c#, certificate, impersonation

I am trying to use authentication based on client certificates in my client/server http application. I also need to impersonate the user after authentication.

Here is what I have done so far:

- client and server have certificates including private key, issued by Let´s Encrypt and supporting both server and client authentication extended key usage
- I assigned a mapping to the active directory user (in fact a computer) using the Subject and Issuer of the client certificate
- I imported the root certificate of Let´s Encrypt to my active directory configuration (see https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/understanding-active-directory-certificate-services-containers-in-active-directory.aspx)  (not sure this is required)
- I configured server certificate with netsh add sslcert .. clientcertnegotiation=enable dsmapperusage=enable
- I enabled my client code to send a client certificate. The certificate is visible in my server code in HttpListener.GetContext().Request.GetCertificate()

however

- HttpListener.GetContext().User is null

what step am I missing? Is there any additional code I need to add to get the authenticated user?

I am using Samba AD DCs in case that matters.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: Mutual SSL only helps create secure communication between client/server, which you have already done. User impersonation with `HttpListener` requires yourself to initial a user instance and map to that specific client certificate. If on IIS you can simply use client certificate mapping to user accounts.